# Count how many times a function has been called

Tags: python, python-3.x, function-call

```
def matrix_mult_rec(M, k):
    
    if (k == 0): 
        return 1
    if(k >=1):
        M_to_power = M * matrix_mult_rec(M, k-1)
      
    return M_to_power
```

I define a function that if you input a matrix and the power, it returns M^k where `M` is a matrix.
I would like to know if `k = 100`, how many times this function has been called.
How should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a class to encapsulate your function, such as:

```
class Func:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnt=0
        
    def __call__(self, arg):
        self.cnt+=1
        # here have your function...
```

Example:

```
my_func=Func()      

for x in range(98):
    my_func(44)
```

The `.cnt` is always available for your inspection:

```
>>> my_func.cnt
98
```

And with this you could use a `while` loop:

```
while my_func.cnt<tgt:
    my_func(arg)
```

You can also pass your function to the object:

```
class Func:
    def __init__(self, proc):
        self.cnt=0
        
    def __call__(self, arg):
        self.cnt+=1
        return proc(arg)
```

Then call like so:

```
def your_func(arg);
    # your func

my_func=Func(your_func) 

while my_func.cnt<tgt:
    my_func(arg)
```

Comment: I think what I've learned does not help me understand what you are saying lol. But I saw some other answers which talk about creating a global variable? or pass a new variable in the function which looks like this: def matrix_mult_rec(M, k, count = 0):

Comment: You can do that too. It is more easily screwed up however since you have to reset your counter each time

Comment: I see you use a class but where do I input the value of k?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a decorator - not sure what is simple for you

```
import functools

def invocation_counter(func):
    inv_counter = 0

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def decorating_function(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal inv_counter
        inv_counter += 1
        func(*args, **kwargs)

    def info():
        return inv_counter

    def clear():
        inv_counter = 0

    decorating_function.clear = clear
    decorating_function.info = info
    return decorating_function
```

then use this this:

```
@invocation_counter
def f1(some_text):
    print(some_text)

f1("Hi")
f1("Hello")
f1("Ciao")
print(f1.info())
```

this prints 3